# Pointing folder to different disk

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

Say I have a D-drive and a folder SomeData. For performance reasons I would like the data in SomeData to be on a different harddisk (SSD), while keeping the paths intact.

So the file D:\SomeData\ImportantFile.txt would still be in that path, even though actually on a different disk.

Can I "mount" (?) a harddisk as a folder below another disk?

I use Win7 Ultimate and NTFS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can mount disks as folders using the *Change drive letter and paths* function in `diskmgmt.msc`, or the `mountvol` command-line tool. (But see below...)

However, even on the new disk, it is usually better to keep the files contained within a directory – to prevent it from becoming one big mess if you ever decide to use the second disk for anything else. This can be done using **junctions** or **[symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)** – both will work fine; symlinks are recommended but they're supported only on Windows Vista and newer versions, while junctions also work on Windows 2000/XP.

To symlink your `SomeData` to a different disk:

1. Move the original directory to the new SSD drive. You must delete the original directory.
2. Open an elevated command prompt.
3. Use the `mklink` utility to create a symbolic link with the same name and location as the original directory:

   ```
   C:\>mklink /d D:\SomeData Z:\SomeData
   ```

   (where `Z:\` is your SSD and `D:\` is the old drive)

On older Windows versions `mklink` is not present, but the [`junction`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) utility from Sysinternals can be used to create junctions.

Comment: Will everything generally work, if I do that, or do some things behave oddly? I am not sure what to specifically ask for, I hope you know what I mean. :)

Comment: Well, I moved my whole Steam directory from the system drive to a larger disk this way and haven't had a problem. Symlinks are transparent to applications unless they specifically look for them.

Comment: @grawity That's one fine edit there!